# session variable increments only once

Tags: php, variables

I am using session values to increment 2 variable across pages with ajax..Simple one..
I have used session_start in Page1 and initialize the session variable to 0 in page 1..
In page2 I am initializing them based on condition.. I seems to increment once, them there is no effect..Here is my action page..

```
    <?php 
session_start(); 
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php

$j=isset($_POST['commit']) && $_POST['commit'];
    if($j)

    {
    $num=rand(0, 100);
    ?>


<div>
    <div id="inner_1">
        <?php 
        if($num<27){ 
            echo "Result:Hit";
            $_SESSION['off']=$_SESSION['off']=+1;
                echo "Offensive Player:";
            if(isset($_SESSION['off'])){echo $_SESSION['off'];}else{echo '0';}
                echo "Defensive Player:";
             if(isset($_SESSION['on'])){echo $_SESSION['on'];}else{echo '0';} 
                } 
        else 
                {
            echo "Result:Miss";
            $_SESSION['on']=$_SESSION['on']=+1;
            echo "Offensive Player:";
            if(isset($_SESSION['off'])){echo $_SESSION['off'];}else{echo '0';}
            echo "Defensive Player:";
            if(isset($_SESSION['on'])){echo $_SESSION['on'];}else{echo '0';}
                }    ?>
    </div>


</div>



    <?php } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Page1

```
        <?php
       session_start();
       $_SESSION['off']=0;
       $_SESSION['on']=0;
       ?>
```

Comment: Those on and off vars....they are flags(also called switches) with 0 or 1 values....or they are like an autoincrement tipe of vars....what are the default base-values of those vars?

Comment: In page1 , I have given them 0 as initial values for both?? If that is causing the trouble??

Comment: But they are switch or autoincrement?

Comment: $_SESSION['off'] = $_SESSION['off']+1; Like this.. SO should I use $_SESSION['off']++ ??

Comment: @RobertRozas But even autoincrement shows the similar result??Any idea??

Answer (score 3):

```
$_SESSION['on']=$_SESSION['on']=+1;
```

What should this do? assign twice `+1` to `$_SESSION['on']`?

To add some number to a variable, use:

```
$_SESSION['on'] += 1;
```

(Do the same for your `$_SESSION['off']`)

Comment: @user2234992 This code will work. Your error is somewhere in your logic, but this is clearly (all the answers) the correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

its because

```
$_SESSION['off']=$_SESSION['off']=+1;
                                 ^
                                 +---unwanted = sign
```

it should be

```
 $_SESSION['off']=$_SESSION['off']+1;
```

also same apply to the `$_SESSION['on']`

Comment: Thanks for replying, but now it show result as 1 for either on or off value??

Comment: it depends on this condition `if($num<27){`

Comment: I just want the values to keep incrementing..Any idea how I can achieve this??

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION['off']=+1` means it assign value 1 to session variable

Change

```
$_SESSION['off']=$_SESSION['off']=+1;
```

to

```
$_SESSION['off'] = $_SESSION['off']+1;
```

also change same as `$_SESSION['on']=$_SESSION['on']=+1;` above

Comment: Thank you.. But no tamil, now am getting result as 1 for either on or off..Any idea??

Comment: I works fine...the output belongs to this line $num=rand(0, 100);

Comment: yes, but I want the values to keep incrementing.. If you could tell me how I can achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

Declare your session variable inside your HTML PAGE in the first php tag and it should solve your problem.