# Cannot increment session variable more than once using AJAX/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I have tried several ways to try and update this session variable more than once (i.e to make it increment for EACH click rather than just the first one), but it is not working.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nextWeek').on('click', function(){
        $.post ('incrementWeek.php', function (response) {
            location.reload();
        });

        location.reload();
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm trying to increment the $_SESSION['idn'] variable for reuse after makes a click on a certain button/link. "incrementWeek.php" is simply:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $session = $_SESSION['idn'];
    $session++;
    $_SESSION['idn'] = $session;
?>
```

Few quick answers to common questions: session_start() is the first thing under the first PHP tag, the $_SESSION['idn'] variable is set earlier in the file, but I use an if structure like this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['idn'])) {

}

else {
    $id = getIDFromDate($connection, $currentSunday);
    $_SESSION['idn'] = $id;
}
```

I tried using an alert to see if the variable changes, but it stayed the same. After the first page load, AJAX (I suppose?) does not even acknowledge that I am clicking the "nextWeek" class button. The page does not reload meaning location.reload() was not executed.

Any ideas are appreciated.

EDIT: Thank you. I have edited the code above from everyone's feedback and now it does not reload the page at all and the $_SESSION variable does not update. Is there something wrong syntactically?

Comment: Firstly you must understand whats the difference between client side and server side programming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [session variable increments only once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153396/session-variable-increments-only-once)

Comment: Javascript runs on client machine and session is on server side. Understandthe difference. you can hit an ajax request to some php function on server to do your job andreturn someoutput to you. that is the only possibility.

Comment: For a session variable to have value set, you need to redirect to an url after setting the session variable on server side. Because you are using the ajax call for setting it up and you will not be able to redirect to an url from the server side here, your session variable is not getting set up. You will need to use an alternate method for your need.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION['idn']++` is not correct. You should do this instead:

```
$session = intval($_SESSION['idn']);
$session++ ;
$_SESSION['idn'] = $session;
```

Comment: or $_SESSION['idn'] = $_SESSION['idn'] + 1;

Answer (score 0):

Setting session variable requires redirection after setting the value in it.

By this logic , becuase you are setting the session using the ajax call, you will not be able to redirect on server side to any url and hence you session variable is not getting set up.

I think your need is to reuse the link clicked count somewhere for some purpose, what you can do here is as an alternate solution is to set your click count in the same ajax server side php file i.e. incrementWeek.php, but not using the session instead try using the cookie in php

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nextWeek').on('click', function(){
        $.post ('incrementWeek.php', function (response) {
            location.reload();
        });

       // location.reload(); // <-- remove this as it is not required
    });
});
</script>
```

And

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if(isset($_SESSION['idn']))
   {
     $_SESSION['idn'] = $_SESSION['idn'] + 1;
   }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

TO use php inside javascript, you need to open php

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nextWeek').on('click', function(){
    // dont do this 
     <?php  $_SESSION['idn']++; ?>
     // instead use a ajax 
      $.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/file',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {"session_increment":1},
    success:function(response){
        if(response==1)
        {
            location.reload();
        }
       }
     });
    });
   });
```

this will work, and will increment the value

Comment: @Meenesh - i doubt this will work as you are trying to increament a server side variable on client side. You can use any server side variable on client side on page load but can not further process on the server side variable being on client side in javascript

Comment: Yeah @RakeshLampStack, i agree with you, then use ajax to increment the session variable, and when your request is successfully executed,  reload the page

Comment: Made Changes to the post, try this server side